# How compiler manages runtime stack?

Tags: c++, stack-allocation

There are lots of questions asked about stack & heap on this site. But i want to know about how compiler manages stack actually? Is the stack based allocation is decided at runtime or compile time?
Consider following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {
 // Test class' data members
 public:
 // member functions
};
int main() {
  Test t; // automatic object
  // use t here
  return 0;
}
```

The question here is when object t will be allocated? memory will be allocated at compile time or runtime? I know that local variables, objects gets allocated when function is called & destroyed when function terminates.

Comment: Doesnt that last sentence answer your question?

Comment: "objects gets allocated when function is called" => when the function is run...

Comment: Usually, the compiler doesn't do anything with the stack.

Comment: In some cases, eg. when a function address is passed off to an external API call, the compiler has not even any idea which stack/s it might be called on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack based allocation is **decided** at compile time and is **executed** at run time. When the compiler "sees" the declaration of `Test t`, it generates code to allocate `sizeof(Test)` bytes on the stack for `t` and optionally to call its ctor. When the function exits, the compiler generates code to call the dtor (if it exists) and to deallocate the space.

However, C99 introduced variable length arrays. They are also allocated on the stack, but their size if determined at run time. See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Compiler takes the decision to have the runtime allocate on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the system actually. a compiler can **estimate** how much memory it needs to allocate when compiling.

However, mostly it is done at runtime because stack use is difficult to estimate because it is code dependent, and can vary between runs depending on the code path that the program takes on execution